# JFace databinding to Draw2d

Tags: java, jface

Is it possible to use the JFace databinding framework to work with Draw2D figure? I mean to write a viewer based on draw2d.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Eclipse Graphiti and Eclipse GMF projects. These projects provide a system to create a graphical editor using draw2d/gef backed by a model.

Comment: Without using of GMF or GEF. Could I simple use the JFace binding features like other widgets?

Comment: You could probably contrive JFace databinding to do this by writing custom extensions. There is nothing out of the box that will do this for you. There are just too many variations of how shapes could map to data model. The graphical editor problem is much bigger than what databinding framework was designed to handle.

Comment: If the GEF is much bigger than databinding framework, should I use GEF or Databinding? Which one could speed me up? I just want to draw some shapes and use the shape to show my model states which don't require the bi-directional operation.

Comment: Apples and oranges. They don't serve the same purpose. If you need to manipulate the diagram on screen, you need GEF, draw2d isn't going to cut it. Once you build a GEF editor, you will want to synchronize it with a model. Here you are on your own. Frameworks like Graphiti and GMF sit on top of GEF and EMF for model to make it easier to create an end-to-end solution.

Comment: Fine, I think I have make the problem more and more complex. The GEF and JFace is not my solution at this time.
Thanks.